# Are forum posts reasonable to use as references?

Tags: discussion

Although I think forum posts are far from ideal references, is it reasonable to link to them when no better verified source material is readily available?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  We don't have a hard "back it up" requirement here, so any source of additional information would be useful.  Certainly the more support you can give the better and the more reputable the sources the better, but any additional information is likely to be helpful.